# cocos2d trying to keep sprites within the screen

Tags: cocos2d-x, sprite, cocos2d-js

So I have theses sprites that move left to right diagonally going upwards. The problem is that they will go upwards infinitely, and moving out of the screen. I want them to move inside a certain boundary.

I tried using clamp but it won't work. I'm fairly new to cocos2d-js so I don't have many ideas. if anybody could help I'll appreciate it.

```
for(var i=0;i<minions.length;i++){

        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * size.width));
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * size.height / 10) + size.height / 50);

        var ms = Math.floor((Math.random() + 1));
        var mas = (size.width - x) / size.width * ms
        var m2s = x / size.width * ms;


        var move = cc.MoveBy.create(mas, cc.p(size.width - x, y));
        var moveaway = cc.MoveBy.create(ms, cc.p(-size.width, -y));
        var move2 = cc.MoveBy.create(m2s, cc.p(x, y));

        var minSeq = cc.Sequence.create(move, moveaway, move2);

        minions[i].runAction(minSeq).repeatForever();

        minions[i].setPosition(cc.p(cc.clampf(minions[i].x,0,size.width),cc.clampf(minions[i].y,0,400)));
        this.addChild(minions[i]);
    }
```

before this I tired an if loop like

if(minions[i].position == 0){//move upwards}

when I was having problems with the sprites going downwards continuously.
it would only work the very first time when the sprites appear below the screen, but after that, it wouldn't have any impact on the sprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the boundaries in screen coordinates first

```
var xMin = 0, yMin = 0, xMax = 320, yMax = 240;
```

Also let's assume there's a global variable which holds array of your minions.

```
var minions = [];
```

I'm pretty sure you've scheduled update already, using `scheduleUpdate()`
so now you can do this check in the `update` function

```
update: function(dt){
   //your code
   minions.forEach(function(minion){
      var p = minion.getPosition();
      if (p.x > pMax) {
         //change minion speed to go down
      } 
      if (p.x < pMin){
        //change minion speed to go up
      }
      // same for y-axis
   });
}
```

Comment: okay so this might be a shit question but I don't know how to call the minions to the update function. they're in the init:fucntion(), and I added a tag 500 so I could use var minions = this.getChildByTag(500). but it keeps saying the var minions in the update function is null

Comment: Well, you can store them in a global variable, or in a additional attribute of gameLayer you've created yourself

Comment: oh I didn't want it to be a global variable but it was the easiest way to fix it lol. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: np man, you can choose the answer as a correct one, to close the question